# Generability of log normal distributed variates

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model, lognormal-distribution

Reworded  question: I have a large number of measurements which altogether seems to come from a log normal distribution (using fitdistrplus in R). Now these measurements are not independent since they come from a smaller number of batches, and what I really want is to know how the distribution is batchwise, assuming it is similar across batches but with varying parameters. If I simulate the generation of measurements from a number of batches each sampled from log normal distribution but with varying parameters the complete ensemble again comes out log normal. But can I know just from finding that the total of measurements is log normal that the individual batches also are this way? I have fitted hierarchical models taking batches into account and the fit is certainly better when log transforming the measurements.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot understand what you're trying to ask.  Your question seems to say "If I decide I have lognormal variables, ... how can I know whether they are lognormally distributed?"  That's doesn't seem to require any answer at all.  I have skipped over stuff like "pr batch" that makes no sense, so perhaps there are typos in your question.  Maybe showing a small but explicit example of your data would help.

Comment: Are you asking whether the conditional distribution and the marginal distribution of the mixture across batches can both be lognormal? It depends on the distribution of the parameters. Generally it won't be both, but can be in some cases - e.g. if the distribution of $\mu_i$ (the logmean for batch $i$) is normal and $\sigma_i^2$ is the same for all $i$, then on the log scale the marginal distribution of your mixture should be normal. If the $\sigma_i^2$ were drawn from an inverse gamma then again, you should get a normal distribution on the log scale.  Is that the kind of thing you're asking?

Comment: Thanks a lot - here is a simulated example         

NGL <- 300
N <- sample(c(5:15),NGL,replace=TRUE)
MNL <- rnorm(NGL,1,.5)
SDL  <- runif(NGL,.5,1)

LNRES <- c()
#i <- 1
for (i in 1:NGL) LNRES <- c(LNRES,rlnorm(N[i],MNL[i],SDL[i]))
   
plot(density(LNRES))
library(fitdistrplus)
descdist(LNRES, boot = 1000)